# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure - not working only for me

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i have a problem with my project.developed with asp.net core ( version 3.1.100 ) - visual studio 16.4.0
but when i start the IIS EXPRESS , it show me this page

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

i try all solutions in all forums & stackoverflow responses .. without any results

in my friend desktop who made the project works great without any problem
but in my desktop , not working !!

when i change the hosting model from "In Process" to "Out Of precss" it show me this

> This localhost page can’t be found
>   No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44365/

here is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:ImmoDbConnectionString"]));

            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "http://dotnetdetail.net",
                    ValidIssuer = "http://dotnetdetail.net",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pintusharmaqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqweqwe"))
                };
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            //SeedDB.Initialize(
            //    app.ApplicationServices
            //        .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
            //        .CreateScope()
            //        .ServiceProvider);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            //    app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: I recently encountered the same problem. I learned where the problem originated. I realized that it was due to a function I used in the background service. Is there a function you wrote yourself and used to get the project up? Have you made a change in Program.cs?[problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61121039/http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure-asp-net-core-3-1)